# What is the most memory efficient representation of a series of 0s and 1s?

Tags: python, math

I have a very large set of binary arrays (100^3), each of length about 1000. The arrays themselves have no specific pattern; they are random. I have to compare all of them to each other, so I cannot depend on disk IO to reduce memory footprint. The best way I know to store 0s and 1s is to use a bit array (in Python, there is a module [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) for this purpose).

Is there a mathematical way to do better? I read something about representing large integers as a list of powers of prime numbers, but decimal equivalent of 1000 bits can be a really large number, probably resulting in the list of integers consuming more memory than 1000 bits.

Comment: Hm, if I get this right 100^3 * 1000 bits is about 128MB. Is there a specific reason that much memory is a problem?

Comment: What kind of comparison do you want to do? If you're simply testing if one bitarray is identical to another in the set you may be able to save space by hashing.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Agreed. I have 128 MB to spare. However, I would love to eventually run multiple instances in parallel. For example, I may want to super-impose 2 bit arrays (in all combinations), and then compare all of the resulting bit arrays.

Comment: @PM2Ring, I am trying to learn parameters for an algorithm that would maximize the 1s in a subset of those arrays, and minimize the 1s in the remaining arrays. I don't understand what you mean by applying hashing here.

Comment: Hashing probably won't help you here. But if you were just testing for equality you could store each bitarray on disk and store their hashes in a list in RAM so you'd only need to load & compare bitarrays if their hashes are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No.

If a series of bits are truly random, then there is nothing you can do to shorten them. An inherent property of something that is random is that there are no patterns. Therefore, you cannot shorten a random sequence of bits.